# Direct sum, dyadic product (Kronecker product), and Hadamard product in Julia

Tags: julia, linear-algebra, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, game-theory

Currently I am trying to implement a Shapley betweenness centrality algorithm in Julia but I am unsure how to compute a direct sum, dyadic product (Kronecker product), and Hadamard product. The algorithm takes in a weighted graph (A) and adjacency matrix (A_2) as an input and outputs a vector containing values of the Shapley Value-based betweenness centrality. I've attached the pseudocode described in the paper below. Here is my code so far:

```
using DataStructures
using LinearAlgebra
using SparseArrays


function ShapelyBetweennessWeighted(A, A_2)
    V = size(A, 1) #number of vertices

    #Distance between nodes
    d = zeros(V, V)

    #list of predecessors on all node pairs
    Pred_s = [[] for i in 1:V]

    #Length of shortest path on each pair
    sigma = zeros(V, V)

    #One-side dependency of source node on target node
    delta = zeros(V, V)
    cSh = zeros(V)

    #Number of shortest paths from s to v with accuracy to the number of
    #vertices belonging to them in stored array
    T = zeros(V,V)

    #Sructs
    Q = PriorityQueue{Float64, Float64}()
    S = []

    
    for s in 1:V
        for v in 1:V
            Pred_s[v] = []; d[s,v] = Inf ; sigma[s,v] = 0
        end
        d[s,s] = 1; sigma[s,s] = 1;
        enqueue!(Q, s)
        while isempty(Q) == false
            for v in 1:V
                Q[v] = d[s, v] #extract v with minimal d[s,v]
            end
            v = dequeue!(Q)
            push!(S, v)
            for w in 1:V
                if A_2[v, w] == 1
                    if d[s, w] > d[s, v] + A[v, w]
                        d[s, w] = d[s, v] + A[v, w]
                        #insert/update w → Q with d[s,w]
                        try
                            Q[w] = d[s,w]
                        catch y
                            Q[y] = d[s, w]
                        end
                        sigma[s, w] = 0; T[s, w] = 0
                        Pred_s[w] = []
                    if d[s, w] == d[s, v] + A[v, w]
                        sigma[s, w] += sigma[s, v]
                        push!(Pred_s[w], v)
                        #T_sw = T_sw tensor product T_sv
                    end
                end
            end
        end
        for v in 1:V
            delta[s, v] = 0
        end
        while length(S) > 0
            w = pop!(S)
            for v in Pred_s[w]
                delta[s, v] += (sigma[s,v]/sigma[s,w])*(1/d[s,w] + delta[s,w])

                #tensor product 
            end
            if w != s
                cSh[w] += delta[s,w] + (2-d[s,w])/d[s,w]

                #tensor product 
            end
        end
    end
    for v in 1:V
        cSh[v] = cSh[v]/2
    end
end
    return cSh
end
```

There are most likely other errors in my code, so any help regarding how to implement the pseudocode in the paper is appreciated http://ifaamas.org/Proceedings/aamas2012/papers/1B_4.pdf. Here is the pseudocode used in the paper:

[image: shapley_betweenness_centrality]

Comment: Well Hadamard is easy, it's built into Julia: `C = A .* B`

Comment: Never use untyped containers in Julia, see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/

Comment: In Julia, Kronecker of A and B arrays is called kron(A, B) and the kron function is in base Julia.